# My Debian repository is throwing a "Hash Sum mismatch" error

Tags: amazon-s3, debian, apt-get

We maintain a Debian repository for an app and all `.deb` files are stored on a s3 bucket.
We wrote a script to upload the files and update the `Packages.gz` file. All went fine until one of the developers found [deb-s3](https://github.com/krobertson/deb-s3) and tried using it.

After the first package upload we started getting this error message:

`W: Failed to fetch s3://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp/dists/test/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch`

I've tried to restore an old version of our Packages.gz file with no success. I've searched for this error and removing the `/var/lib/apt/lists/` does not work either.

What would `deb-s3` do that could break our entire repo?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `deb-s3` creates a `Releases` file under dist/test and that conflicts with Packages.gz.
Removing the `Release` file restored our repository back to what it was.